# How to create a list and then iterate to print data using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Now I want to print all the date like "03/17/2018" in Selenium WebDriver, and here is my HTML inspect in Chrome:

```
<div id="ember3175" class="ember-view encounter-list"><header class="box-margin-Bsm"><h3 class="header3a">Encounters</h3></header>
<section class="d-complex-list-container box-padding-Tsm-v2 type-v2">
                <div class="item box-padding-TBxs-v2">
                    <span class="link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2">03/17/2018</span>
                    <span>Encounter (Patient Phone Message)</span>
<!---->                    <div class="chief-complaint">
                        <span class="p-666">CC:</span>
                            <span>Pt. called to follow-up on monospot results.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item box-padding-TBxs-v2">
                    <span class="link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2">02/17/2018</span>
                    <span>Encounter (SOAP Note)</span>
<!---->                    <div class="chief-complaint">
                        <span class="p-666">CC:</span>
                            <span>chronic sinusitis</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item box-padding-TBxs-v2">
                    <span class="link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2">01/17/2018</span>
                    <span>Encounter (SOAP Note)</span>
<!---->                    <div class="chief-complaint">
                        <span class="p-666">CC:</span>
                            <span>nasal congestion</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item box-padding-TBxs-v2">
                    <span class="link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2">11/17/2017</span>
                    <span>Encounter (SOAP Note)</span>
<!---->                    <div class="chief-complaint">
                        <span class="p-666">CC:</span>
                            <span>nasal congestion</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item box-padding-TBxs-v2">
                    <span class="link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2">10/17/2016</span>
                    <span>Encounter (SOAP Note)</span>
                        <span class="link-text icon-lock"></span>
                    <div class="chief-complaint">
                        <span class="p-666">CC:</span>
                            <span>nasal congestion</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!----></section>
</div>
```

Now I can print any single date with its XPath as:

```
String time = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember3175\"]/section/div[2]/span[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(time);
```

But I want to iterator all the date and print all the date, I tried:

```
int size = driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id=\"ember3175\"]/section/div/span[1]")).size();
```

To get the size of all the children element, but there is an error that I cannot get its size. So my question is how I iterate and print all the dates here? Also, If I want to do iterative jobs in other tables, how can I choose the parent? I mean most time I could get any single data with its XPath in Chrome, but when I want to iterate all the data, I do not know how to choose the parent and get its size. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to print all the **dates** under the heading **Encounters** and you can create a *List* of the **dates** under the heading **Encounters** and print them using the following code block :

Code Block :

```
List<WebElement> encounterDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='header3a' and contains(.,'Encounters')]//following::section[@class='d-complex-list-container box-padding-Tsm-v2 type-v2']//span[@class='link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2']"));
for (WebElement ele : encounterDates) 
    System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Console Output :

```
03/17/2018
02/17/2018
01/17/2018
11/17/2017
10/17/2016
```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. Now I can print all the dates in the console. But how did you know the parent xPath "//h3[@class='header3a' and contains(.,'Encounters')]//following::section[@class='d-complex-list-container box-padding-Tsm-v2 type-v2']//span[@class='link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2']"? Did you find it in fireBug or Chrome Inspect? Or you wrote it by yourself? I would like to learn the method so I could deal with similar problem in the future. Thanks. When I tried in my Chrome inspect, and fetch the part like parent which is covering all the children. I get xpath "//*[@id="ember3180"]/section"

Comment: @YangWang I am afraid, the _xpath_ wasn't found through _FireBug_ or _Chrome Inspect_. **3180** as in `ember3180` looks dynamic to me. So it may not help us much to locate any unique element constantly.

Comment: I have accepted you. Here is my another question about selenium in my work :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123421/how-to-grab-lists-of-data-by-col-and-print-one-by-one-in-a-table-using-selenium   Could you look at it and give me some advice? I think I need to learn how to write Xpath  by HTML to solve my problems in my work, right?

Answer (score 1):

1) Getting a single element:

```
WebElement time = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember3175\"]/section/div[2]/span[1]"));
```

2) Getting a series of elements:

```
List<WebElement> time2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember3175\"]/section/div[2]/span"));
```

The differences are:

- `findElement` vs `findElements` - you need the plural version to get multiple elements.
- Do not specify the [#] for the span. Saying `span[1]` will only match the first occurrence, but `span` will match all the possibilities.

Comment: You've got .getText() on the end of both these statements, I don't think that was your intention.  List<WebElement> doesn't have a .getText() method.

Comment: @anonygoose, good catch. I updated the code to just be WebElements. That will teach me to trust my cut and paste skills without looking

Answer (score 1):

You can take number of elements which has same class, by using findElements and ListElements:

```
 List<WebElement> findValue = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2']"));

 for (WebElement webElement : findValue) {
 String printValue = webElement.getText();
 System.out.println(printGroupName);
 }
```

Here `List<E>` is `List array`, which stores all elements from `DOM` which is containing above span class and `Webelement` will retrieve text from span class.

Comment: Thanks Ishita. Now I can print all the dates in the console. But how did you know the parent xPath "//span[@class='link-text box-margin-Rsm-v2']"?  Did you find it in fireBug or Chrome Inspect? Or you wrote it by yourself? I would like to learn the method so I could deal with similar problem in the future. Thanks

Comment: @YangWang, From the HTML which you have provided.

Comment: @YangWang Please accept this answer with Up vote, so other readers may refer this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get all dates:

```
public List<WebElement> allDates(){  

List<WebElement> allDates = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class$='link-text box-margin-Rsm']"));  

for(WebElement elements : allDates){  

System.out.println(elements.getText());

}  
    return allDates;  
}
```