# How to identify and print lists of data from a table using Selenium and WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a table and want to grab data by col and then print every piece of data one by one. Here is what the table looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F60c.png

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ember10911" class="ember-view flowsheet-table">
    <div class="header flowsheet-column">
        <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-row"> </div>
        <div id="ember10912" class="ember-view flowsheet-row header-row">
            <h4 class="header4semibold " data-ember-action="10913">
                <div class="ellipsis" style="width: 302px">Vitals</div>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="ember10914" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Height </div>
        <div id="ember10915" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Weight </div>
        <div id="ember10916" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> BMI </div>
        <div id="ember10917" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> BP </div>
        <div id="ember10918" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Temperature </div>
        <div id="ember10919" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Pulse </div>
        <div id="ember10920" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Respiratory rate </div>
        <div id="ember10921" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> O2 Saturation </div>
        <div id="ember10922" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Pain </div>
        <div id="ember10923" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Head Circumference </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flowsheet-scroll-region">
        <div id="ember11083" class="ember-view flowsheet-column">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-table-header selectable" data-ember-action="11084">
                <div class="p-semibold">08/24/17</div>
                <div class="p-semibold">8:44 PM</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember11086" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell header-row"> </div>
            <div id="ember11088" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"> </div>
            <div id="ember11090" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable">
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">152 </span>
                <span class="p-666" data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">lb</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember11092" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"> </div>
            <div id="ember11094" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable wide-cell">
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">102/64 </span>
                <span class="p-666" data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">mmHg</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember11096" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable">
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">97.9 </span>
                <span class="p-666" data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">°F</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember11098" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable">
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">72 </span>
                <span class="p-666" data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">bpm</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember11100" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"> </div>
            <div id="ember11102" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"> </div>
            <div id="ember11104" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"> </div>
            <div id="ember11106" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember4341\"]"));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print("Date" + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember4929\"]/div[1]/div[1]")) + "Height" + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember4944\"]/span[1]")) + "Weight" + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember4946\"]/span[1]"))+......);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I want to use a list to store each col's information, and then use a for loop to go through it. What I expect is:

```
    "Date 10/17/16 Height 64 Weight 106........."
    "Date 11/17/17 Height 64 Weight 109.99......"

.......
```

But what I got is:

```
"Date[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (bf163179196c60704f582de0d421323c)] -> xpath: //*[@id="ember4929"]/div[1]/div[1]]Height[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (bf163179196c60704f582de0d421323c)] -> xpath: //*[@id="ember4944"]/span[1]]Weight[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (bf163179196c60704f582de0d421323c)] -> xpath: //*[@id="ember4946"]/span[1]]"
```

I also tried to just get first col's data and print, I use code:

```
System.out.println("Date: " + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ember5060 > div.flowsheet-cell.flowsheet-table-header.selectable > div:nth-child(1)")).getText() + "  " + "Height: " + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ember5075 > div")).getText() + "   " + "Weight: " + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ember5077 > div")).getText());
```

and it worked. I got:

```
Date: 10/25/17  Height: 67 in   Weight: 139.99 lb
```

Now I can print the first col's data, But I do not know how to do it iteratively and print each col in the table. So what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: The HTML you have provided doesn't contains the elements representing the texts **Height**, **Weight**, etc

Comment: @DebanjanB Hi man, I just updated the HTML code, first I omitted the header part because I did not know how to combine header and body . So I just printed String "Height", "Weight"  and did not use Xpath in my code.Thanks

Comment: You should be first finding a COL, then each rows in that COL then extract each items in that row and print it out.

Comment: It's hard to read your html code, otherwise I would give you a code suggestion to try out.

Comment: Your first column date div is missing `flowsheet-column-date` class.  Is that an error in your HTML or does the script need to account for that?

Comment: @JoeCoder actually in the webpage there is no "date" property, I add it myself, so I can distinguish each col by date. But the problem is that I cannot print data even though without "date" property.

Comment: It seems you've also combined the value and units div, rendering the answer I was working on incorrect.  Please let us know when you have finalized your HTML.

Comment: @JoeCoder Sorry man. It is kind of weird because when I switch to another account, it combines the unit and value..... Anyway, let's use the original one which split value and unit , and I have rolled back to that version. Thx

Comment: No worries.  Awaiting final HTML with separate units and values...

Comment: @JoeCoder  Hi buddy, I find that in my data set sometimes it combines units and values, sometime it does not.....Even in the same table...These two exist together. I do not know why. But now I replace the messy one with new HTML, Which split value and unit. But it only contains one col... But let's assume it may have several cols, because for other user there may be several cols. Also, it does have some null values. In my current case, it misses Height, BMI. I have no idea how to check which is missed now. You have any idea? thx

Comment: Ah ok.  Good to know, thanks.  I noticed in your original data, the final column was empty.  It might be a good idea to include a full table so that such conditions can be handled without throwing an exception for an expected element being missing.

Comment: @JoeCoder  Yes, it seems that no matter how many cols I have, it will add three empty cols in the last. But I found that in the col, missing data also has a div, it doesn't skip to next data directly.  For example. "<div id="ember11088" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"><!----></div>" represents "height" in my case. And there is no data for height, so there is no value in this div, can we use this to distinguish null data?

Comment: Sure.  But now you have 10 labels in your header and only 4 data cells...

Comment: @JoeCoder   I think the ten data cells should be <div id="ember11088">, <div id="ember11090">,<div id="ember11092">,<div id="ember11094">,<div id="ember11096">,<div id="ember11098">,<div id="ember11100">,<div id="ember11102">,<div id="ember11104">,<div id="ember11106">, and only 90, 94, 96, 98 contains data so it means "Weight", "BP", "Temperature", "Pulse" contains data and rest six properties are null value?

Comment: I moved forward with the assumption that columns with actual data would have the date element present.

Answer (score 0):

The question had several HTML revisions, and this is the one I used to come up with the solution:

```
<div id="ember4342" class="ember-view flowsheet-table">
    <div class="header flowsheet-column">
        <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-row">
        </div>
        <div id="ember4352" class="ember-view flowsheet-row header-row">
            <h4 class="header4semibold " data-ember-action="4353">
                <div class="ellipsis" style="width: 694px">Vitals</div>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="ember4355" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Height
        </div>
        <div id="ember4357" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Weight
        </div>
        <div id="ember4359" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> BMI
        </div>
        <div id="ember4361" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> BMI Percentile
        </div>
        <div id="ember4363" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> BP
        </div>
        <div id="ember4365" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Temperature
        </div>
        <div id="ember4367" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Pulse
        </div>
        <div id="ember4369" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Respiratory rate
        </div>
        <div id="ember4371" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> O2 Saturation
        </div>
        <div id="ember4373" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Pain
        </div>
        <div id="ember4375" class="ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis"> Head Circumference
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flowsheet-scroll-region">
        <div id="ember5636" class="ember-view flowsheet-column">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-table-header selectable" data-ember-action="5637">
                <!---->
                <div class="p-semibold">10/17/16</div>
                <div class="p-semibold"><!----></div>
                <!----></div>
            <div id="ember5639" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell header-row"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5641" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">64 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                   data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">in</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5643" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">106 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                    data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">lb</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5645" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">18.19 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                      data-element="flowsheet-cell-units"><!----></span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5647" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5649" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable wide-cell"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">111/83 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                       data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">mmHg</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5651" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">100.9 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                      data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">°F</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5653" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">86 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                   data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">bpm</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5655" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">14 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                   data-element="flowsheet-cell-units">bpm</span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5657" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5659" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5661" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
        </div>
        <div id="ember5663" class="ember-view flowsheet-column editable">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-table-header selectable" data-ember-action="5664">
                <!---->
                <div class="p-link-semibold" data-element="flowsheet-column-date">11/17/17</div>
                <div class="p-link-semibold" data-element="flowsheet-column-time"><!----></div>
                <!----></div>
            <div id="ember5666" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell header-row"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5668" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">64 in</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5670" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">109.99 lb</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5672" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">18.88 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                      data-element="flowsheet-cell-units"><!----></span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5674" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5676" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable wide-cell"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">116/72 mmHg</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5678" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">101.2 °F</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5680" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">87 bpm</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5682" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">16 bpm</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5684" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5686" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5688" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
        </div>
        <div id="ember5690" class="ember-view flowsheet-column editable">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-table-header selectable" data-ember-action="5691">
                <!---->
                <div class="p-link-semibold" data-element="flowsheet-column-date">01/17/18</div>
                <div class="p-link-semibold" data-element="flowsheet-column-time"><!----></div>
                <!----></div>
            <div id="ember5693" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell header-row"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5695" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">64 in</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5697" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">106 lb</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5699" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">18.19 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                      data-element="flowsheet-cell-units"><!----></span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5701" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5703" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable wide-cell"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">123/84 mmHg</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5705" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">100.3 °F</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5707" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">77 bpm</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5709" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">14 bpm</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5711" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5713" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5715" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
        </div>
        <div id="ember5717" class="ember-view flowsheet-column editable">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell flowsheet-table-header selectable" data-ember-action="5718">
                <!---->
                <div class="p-link-semibold" data-element="flowsheet-column-date">02/17/18</div>
                <div class="p-link-semibold" data-element="flowsheet-column-time"><!----></div>
                <!----></div>
            <div id="ember5720" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell header-row"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5722" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">64 in</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5724" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">106 lb</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5726" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <span data-element="flowsheet-cell-value" class="">18.19 </span><span class="p-666"
                                                                                      data-element="flowsheet-cell-units"><!----></span>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5728" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5730" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable wide-cell"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">121/70 mmHg</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5732" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">100.8 °F</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5734" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">77 bpm</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5736" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----><!---->
                <div data-element="flowsheet-cell-value-and-units" class="p-link">18 bpm</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ember5738" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5740" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
            <div id="ember5742" class="ember-view flowsheet-cell selectable"><!----></div>
        </div>
        <div id="ember5743" class="ember-view flowsheet-column flowsheet-add-column current-context">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5744">
                <a class="icon icon-add" data-element="flowsheet-add-column-button"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell header-row"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5745"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5746"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5747"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5748"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5749"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5750"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5751"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5752"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5753"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5754"></div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell selectable" data-ember-action="5755"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ember4390" class="ember-view"><!----></div>

    <div id="ember4399" class="ember-view"><!---->
        <!----></div>

    <div id="ember4400" class="ember-view"><!----></div>
</div>
```

Here is the full script.  It takes a few seconds to run, because there were some short but necessary timeouts to endure due to potential variances in the units and values element structure:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WebDriverScratch {

    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER = "C:\\Users\\Joe\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
    private static final String HTML_FILE = "file:///C:/Users/Joe/IdeaProjects/scratch/src/main/resources/test.html";
    private static final long SHORT_TIMEOUT = 1;                // 1 second
    private static final long VERY_SHORT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 100;  // 100 milliseconds
    private static final String EMPTY = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        driver.get(HTML_FILE);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(SHORT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.header div.flowsheet-row.ellipsis"));
        List<WebElement> dateElms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.flowsheet-table-header div:first-child"));
        List<ColumnData> cols = new ArrayList<>(dateElms.size());
        for (WebElement date : dateElms) {
            // parse the data for this column
            ColumnData col = new ColumnData(date.getText());
            WebElement column = date.findElement(By.xpath("../.."));
            List<WebElement> dataCells = column.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.ember-view.flowsheet-cell:not(.header-row)"));
            for (int i = 0; i < dataCells.size(); i++) {
                // get the header label by index
                WebElement dataCell = dataCells.get(i);
                String label = labels.get(i).getText();
                WebElement valueAndUnits = findElementOrNull(driver, dataCell, By.cssSelector("div[data-element='flowsheet-cell-value-and-units']"));
                if (valueAndUnits != null) {
                    col.addEntry(label, valueAndUnits.getText());
                } else {
                    // could be empty data cell, or separate value and units
                    WebElement value = findElementOrNull(driver, dataCell, By.cssSelector("span[data-element='flowsheet-cell-value']"));
                    if (value != null) {
                        // since value element is present, assume units element is too
                        WebElement units = dataCell.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-element='flowsheet-cell-units']"));
                        col.addEntry(label, value.getText(), units.getText());
                    } else {
                        // empty data
                        col.addEntry(label, EMPTY);
                    }
                }
            }
            // done parsing data for this column
            cols.add(col);
        }
        driver.close();

        // print it all out
        printData(cols);
    }

    /**
     * simple container for holding parsed data
     */
    private static class ColumnData {

        public class Entry {
            public final String label;
            public final String valueAndUnits;

            public Entry(String label, String valueAndUnits) {
                this.label = label;
                this.valueAndUnits = valueAndUnits;
            }
        }

        public final String date;
        public final List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        public ColumnData(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public void addEntry(String label, String valueAndUnits) {
            entries.add(new Entry(label, valueAndUnits));
        }

        public void addEntry(String label, String value, String units) {
            entries.add(new Entry(label, String.format("%s %s", value, units)));
        }
    }

    private static WebDriver getDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROME_DRIVER);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    /**
     * returns null if element is not present
     */
    private static WebElement findElementOrNull(WebDriver driver, SearchContext parent, By by) {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(VERY_SHORT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        try {
            return parent.findElement(by);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(SHORT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    private static void printData(List<ColumnData> allData) {
        for (ColumnData data : allData) {
            System.out.println("Date: " + data.date);
            for (ColumnData.Entry entry : data.entries) {
                System.out.println(String.format("  %s: %s", entry.label, entry.valueAndUnits));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 10/17/16
  Height: 64 in
  Weight: 106 lb
  BMI: 18.19 
  BMI Percentile: 
  BP: 111/83 mmHg
  Temperature: 100.9 °F
  Pulse: 86 bpm
  Respiratory rate: 14 bpm
  O2 Saturation: 
  Pain: 
  Head Circumference: 
Date: 11/17/17
  Height: 64 in
  Weight: 109.99 lb
  BMI: 18.88 
  BMI Percentile: 
  BP: 116/72 mmHg
  Temperature: 101.2 °F
  Pulse: 87 bpm
  Respiratory rate: 16 bpm
  O2 Saturation: 
  Pain: 
  Head Circumference: 
Date: 01/17/18
  Height: 64 in
  Weight: 106 lb
  BMI: 18.19 
  BMI Percentile: 
  BP: 123/84 mmHg
  Temperature: 100.3 °F
  Pulse: 77 bpm
  Respiratory rate: 14 bpm
  O2 Saturation: 
  Pain: 
  Head Circumference: 
Date: 02/17/18
  Height: 64 in
  Weight: 106 lb
  BMI: 18.19 
  BMI Percentile: 
  BP: 121/70 mmHg
  Temperature: 100.8 °F
  Pulse: 77 bpm
  Respiratory rate: 18 bpm
  O2 Saturation: 
  Pain: 
  Head Circumference:
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the lines e.g. **Date 10/17/16 Height 64 Weight 106.........** you can create 3 *Lists*, one for the **items** in *Vitals* column, one for the **values**, another for the **units**. Now you can place this operation within a function which will accept the desired **date** as an input argument and print the relevant data as follows :

```
public void printReport(String myDate)
{
    List<WebElement> row_Heads = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ember-view flowsheet-table']/div[@class='header flowsheet-column']//div[@class='ember-view flowsheet-row ellipsis']"));
    List<WebElement> rowValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='flowsheet-scroll-region']//div[@class='ember-view flowsheet-column']//div[@class='p-semibold'][.='" + myDate + "']//following::div[contains(@class,'ember-view') and contains(@class,'flowsheet-cell') and contains(@class,'selectable')]/span[@data-element='flowsheet-cell-value']"));    
    List<WebElement> row_Units = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='flowsheet-scroll-region']//div[@class='ember-view flowsheet-column']//div[@class='p-semibold'][.='" + myDate + "']//following::div[contains(@class,'ember-view') and contains(@class,'flowsheet-cell') and contains(@class,'selectable')]//span[@data-element='flowsheet-cell-units']")); 
    for(int i=0; i<rowValues.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(row_Heads.get(i).getText() + " : " + rowValues.get(i).getText()  + " " + row_Units.get(i).getText());
}
```

You can call the function `printReport()` from anywhere within your script to print the relevant data of the respective date as follows :

```
printReport("10/17/16")
printReport("11/17/17")
printReport("01/17/18")
printReport("02/17/18")
```

Comment: Very succinct answer compared to mine, but doesn't handle the case where units and values are combined in a `flowsheet-cell-value-and-units` element as described in the comments on the question.